# how can i send an image to stimulsoft web report from database

Tags: asp.net, stimulsoft

i am new in stimulsoft report
i wanna to send and show an image from database sql to stimulsoft report.
how can i do it?
i use asp.net C#
I create a datatable in behind code and set data into datatable to bind to report
a field of this datatable is Image datatype that i fill it by System.Drowing.Image object.

```
string normalPath = Server.MapPath("Pics\\Other\\PrintPage.gif");
FileStream fsN = new FileStream(normalPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
System.Drawing.Image normalImage = new System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fsN);
fsN.Close();

DataTable result = new DataTable();
result.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5]{
new DataColumn("LineNumber",typeof(int)),
new DataColumn("SerialNumber",typeof(int)),
new DataColumn("ActivationCode",typeof(string)),
new DataColumn("DetectorTypeId",typeof(int)),
new DataColumn("Image",typeof(System.Drawing.Image))
});

Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport stiReport = new Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport();
ds.Tables.Add(result);
stiReport.Load(Server.MapPath("CustomerActivator.mrt"));
stiReport.Render();
stiReport.RegData("Data", result);
StiWebViewer1.Report = stiReport;
StiWebViewer1.Visible = true;
```

Comment: You should change the Render line and the RegData line .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the Data Column property of the Image in the report template.